# How to count two arrays in a single label in UITableViewCell? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, message-queue

I want to create a message conversation screen.I have two arrays, first is `web_array` and the second is `local_array`. First, I have one `UITableViewCell` in one `UILabel`, and one `UITextField`, and one `UIButton`. In the textfield, write any text and it will print on `UITableViewCell` label. TextField text is stored in a one array (`local_array`). (application run time local_array is empty).

And second array (`web_array`), `web_array` is stored in a web service get data, I want to `web_array` count on `UITableViewCell` label after `local_array` count in same label.

`web_array` data counting is over after just down `local_array` data counting start.

My english is very bad and i can't explain proper. seriously i'm so tired please help me and guide.

## ViewController

```
#import "Chat_ViewController.h"
#import "chatview_Cell.h"
@interface Chat_ViewController ()  <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
NSArray*web_array;
NSMutableArray*Local_array;
}
@end

@implementation Chat_ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
Local_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MYURL"]];

//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"senderid=%@&recid=%@&",_chat_myuid.text,_chat_uid.text, nil];

//Check The Value what we passed
NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];


NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
web_array = [results valueForKey:@"message"];
NSLog(@"your message %@",web_array);


//This is for Response
NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
if(resSrt)
{
    NSLog(@"got response");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}
}

- (IBAction)send:(id)sender 
{
 NSString *textNameToAdd = self.mymsg.text;  //mymsg is UITextField outlet
 [Local_array addObject:textNameToAdd];
 [self.table_view reloadData];
}
```

//TABLEVIEWCELL  Code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if ([Local_array count] > 0 && web_array.count>0)
{
    return [Local_array count];
}
else
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

chatview_Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ht"];
if (cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

if (Local_array.count > 0 && web_array.count>0) 
{
    
 cell.other_msg.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Local_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
 cell.other_msg.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[web_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

 return  cell;
}
```

Comment: FYI : in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, cell.other_msg label will always print the value from `web_array` because there is no else condition.

Comment: every thing condition i will try but both array not count in a label.

Comment: i'm not getting your question properly. what you want to show in Label? do you want to show the `web_array`or `Local_array` text in label? or both array data in label ?

Comment: textfield text print on label and web_array print on same label. i want a message conversation screen

Comment: i think you need two section in table. One for Local_array and another for web_array.

Comment: local_array storred a textfield text but web_array counting finish after local_array counting start. do you understand?

Comment: If you want to mix the messages like iMessage etc then you need to combine both sets of messages into a single array, sorted by time. I would suggest you create a class to go in your array, with a property that indicates whether it is a local or server message, so you can use the right cell type

Comment: @Paulw You are correct, please explain in details.